# How long it take to train English/Russian/... model from scratch with SyntaxNet/DragNN?

Tags: tensorflow, syntaxnet

I want to retrain existing models for SyntaxNet/DragNN and looking for some real numbers how long does it take to train models for any language (it will give me good baseline for my languages).
What hardware have you used during this process?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it took about 24 hours on my mac pro with cpu.
(10000 iterations)
https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet

Comment: What model you have trained?

Comment: UD_English corpus.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps a lot. Can you please tell configuration of your mac pro/year?

Comment: my spec is : MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7, 16GB 1600 MHz DDR3, AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB, Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB